# Azure Data Factory Recursive Query in source option

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, recursive-query

I'm trying to execute a recursive query in Azure Data Factory Source using the query option.

[image]

However, even writting **go** or **;** before the **with** sentence, Data Factory is not able to project the columns. If I write (before the with clause):

- "Go", I've got this error `"shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'r'. If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon."`
- If I write ";", I've got this one `shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ';'.`
- If I do not write anything s`haded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.`

So I wonder if this kind of code is not allowed in Azure Data Factory, or if there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you can enter into the Data Flow's Source Options is extremely limited as it doesn't even support `order by` clauses. You can reference a user-defined function, however, so you could nest your CTE inside a UDF and then reference that from Source Options.

REF: [Source transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#source-transformation)

> Query: If you select Query in the input field, enter a SQL query for your source. This setting overrides any table that you've chosen in the dataset. Order By clauses aren't supported here, but you can set a full SELECT FROM statement. You can also use user-defined table functions. select * from udfGetData() is a UDF in SQL that returns a table. This query will produce a source table that you can use in your data flow. Using queries is also a great way to reduce rows for testing or for lookups.

Comment: This is a shame. It forces to create a new object in the database, something we were trying to avoid. It should be considered a possible improvement in Azure Data Factory.